# Cocos2D Get All Contacted Bodies

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone

I am currently converting from `SpriteKit` to `Cocos2d-swift`, and I am trying to find the equivalent of `node.physicsBody.allContactedBodies()`. Is there one? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CCPhysicsBody` has got the [eachCollisionPair method](http://cocos2d.spritebuilder.com/docs/api/Classes/CCPhysicsBody.html#//api/name/eachCollisionPair:) that basically does the same thing. Edit: it has got some limitations, though, see [this](http://forum.cocos2d-objc.org/t/help-with-eachcollisionpair-method/14563/2)

Example:

```
func getCollisions(pair: CCPhysicsCollisionPair!) {
 //do code with the collision pair   
}
```

And here is how you actually call it:

```
physicsBody.eachCollisionPair(self.getCollisions)
```

Comment: Yeah I actually just saw that. However, I am having trouble converting that syntax to swift from obj-c. Do you think you could help me out with an example? Not sure what I need for the argument.

Comment: Nevermind I figure it out. I will propose an edit to your answer which contains an example to help others.